# How do I access array elements stored in a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I'm working on a script and trying to get some values from an array stored in a hash. After searching on Google, searching for questions on SO (and there are some with similar titles but which have remained unsolved or solve problems a little bit different than mine), and after checking out the [Data Structures Cookbook](http://p3rl.org/dsc) and trying everything reasonable to try, I've come to ask your help.

I have a hash, `$action`, and an array, `$action->{'Events'}`. Here's the output for `print Dumper($action->{'Events'});`:

```
$VAR1 = [{
    'Muted'        => 'something',
    'Role'         => 'something',
    'Event'        => 'something',
    'Channel'      => 'something',
    'Talking'      => 'something',
    'UserNumber'   => 'somenumber',
    'CallerIDName' => 'somenumber',
    'Conference'   => 'somenumber',
    'MarkedUser'   => 'something',
    'ActionID'     => 'somenumber',
    'CallerIDNum'  => 'somenumber',
    'Admin'        => 'something'
}];
```

I need to get, for example, the value of `$action->{'EVENTS'}->{'CallerIDName'}`, but this syntax and many other won't work. I've even tried `$action->{'EVENTS'}[6]` and `$action->{'EVENTS'}->[6]` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Array of hashes, try this way:

```
$action->{'EVENTS'}[0]->{'CallerIDName'}
```

see [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES) for more detail.

---

**Updated** example like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $action = {};
$action->{'Events'} = [{'Muted' => 'something',
            'Role' => 'something',
            'Event' => 'something',
            'Channel' => 'something',
            'Talking' => 'something',
            'UserNumber' => 'somenumber',
            'CallerIDName' => 'somenumber',
            'Conference' => 'somenumber',
            'MarkedUser' => 'something',
            'ActionID' => 'somenumber',
            'CallerIDNum' => 'somenumber',
            'Admin' => 'something'}];
#push hash into the array of hashes
push(@{$action->{'Events'}},{'Muted' => 'something',
              'Role' => 'something1',
              'Event' => 'something1',
              'Channel' => 'something1',
              'Talking' => 'something1',
              'UserNumber' => 'somenumber1',
              'CallerIDName' => 'somenumber1',
              'Conference' => 'somenumber1',
              'MarkedUser' => 'something1',
              'ActionID' => 'somenumber1',
              'CallerIDNum' => 'somenumber1',
              'Admin' => 'something1'} );
 for(my $i=0; $i < @{$action->{'Events'}}; $i++){
    print Dumper($action->{Events}[$i]); #print entire hash in array index $i
    #print callerIDName key(any key) of each hash
    print Dumper($action->{'Events'}[$i]->{'CallerIDName'});  
 }
```

Comment: can you help me further by providing a way to iterate through the hashes in $action->{'Events'} ?

Comment: thank you, i've already found a way to iterate when you've wrote to post another topic. But your effort is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The one you're missing is that the $action contains a reference to an array, so the next part must dereference the array.  Then within that is a hash, and you need to dereference the hash.  So it should look like this:

```
$action->{'EVENTS'}[0]{'CallerIDname'}
```

(note that the ->'s beyond the first are optional, so this is fine as well:

```
$action->{'EVENTS'}->[0]->{'CallerIDname'}
```

And does the exact same thing)

Answer (score 1):

The [ ] on the outside indicate the hash is inside an array. So try:

```
  $action->{Events}->[0]->{CallerIDName}
```

You can omit the -> between the {Events} and [0], but I prefer it for clarity. It doesn't make a difference here, but it does in other places. Compare:

```
  @array = (1,2,3); 
  $arrayref = \@array; 
  print $arrayref[0];    # accesses non-existent array @arrayref

  print $arrayref->[0];  # '1'
```